# Getting "Execute Process Task Error: File/Process > "*C:\Users\username\pythonProgram.exe*" not in path" while running via SSISDB

Tags: python, ssis, etl, database-administration

I am trying to automate a SSIS package which consists of a **Execute Process Task** and a **Execute SQL task**. I am calling a **python** executable via Process Task

While running the package in **SSDT(Visual Studio)**, it runs perfectly fine but when i try to deploy it in **Management Studio(SSISDB)**, execute process task throws up following error.[image]

> "Execute Process Task Error: File/Process
>   "*C:\Users\username\pythonProgram.exe*" not in path".

While trying to debug, i removed the execute process task in the same package, deployed a fresh copy of the package and it ran successfully even via Management Studio. I am sure it is the python exe file path causing problem.

I tried to run via **DTexec.exe cmd** utility and facing same problems(running successfully via SSDT but not via Management Studio). 
Here is the command i used
"`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /F "C:\Users\Username\source\repos\TaxAutomation\Package.dtsx" >log.txt"`

After seeing various articles, i asked my DBA to put my .exe file in the Server where Management Studio is located and facing same error.

I am trying to resolve this for last two days and worried that me whole work could be undone if i am not able to automate the package by deploying it in SSISDB or using dtexe cmd utlity. My lack of DBA expertise is making me frustrated and anxious.

I will really appreciate help on this.

Comment: Please make sure that the folder and file exist **on the server** and that the account used for automation has access to it.

Comment: Thanks. Luckily it did work for me. I did not had access to the network drive previously.